# EF Mapping tables Error: Invalid column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am getting the "Invalid column name" error and I strongly believe its because my mapping is wrong.

I am using C# and database first.

My tables are as follow:

icotb001_unidades_c ---- gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c ------ gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m

(id)nu_unidade ------------ (id)nu_unidade ------------------------------ (id)co_posto

no_unidade-----------------  (fk)co_posto---------------------------------- no_posto

Trying to make it clear:

icotb001_unidades_c-- 0..1:1 -- gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c -- M:1 -- gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m

gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c is inheriting from icotb001_unidades_c. That's why it's not a typcal on-to-many relatioship.

Using database first, the table gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c was not created and the other tables has the following code:

```
public partial class icotb001_unidades_c 
{
    public icotb001_unidades_c ()
    {         
    }

    [Key]
    public string nu_unidade { get; set; }

    public string no_unidade{ get; set; }

    public virtual gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m { get; set; }
}

public partial class gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m
{
    public gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m()
    {
         icotb001_unidades_c = new HashSet<icotb001_unidades_c>();
    }

    [Key]
    [StringLength(9)]
    public string co_posto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string no_posto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<icotb001_unidades_c> icotb001_unidades_c { get; set; }
}
```

It wasn't created any fluent API between then either. I searched [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618337/ef-mapping-table-error-invalid-column-name-xxx-id) answered question, but couldn't get it working.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

I changed the above table names to make it clear with the table statements below.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m](
    [co_posto] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [no_posto] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_gedtbd039_posto_atendimento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [co_posto] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 98) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

---------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[icotb001_unidades_c](
    [nu_unidade] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [no_unidade] [varchar](70) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_icotb001_unidades_c] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [nu_unidade] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 98) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

---------

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c](
    [co_posto] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [nu_unidade] [char](4) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_gedtbd042_vinculacao_posto_atendimento] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [nu_unidade] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 98) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_gedtbd042_vinculacao_posto_atendimento_gedtbd039_posto_atendimento] FOREIGN KEY([co_posto])
REFERENCES [dbo].[gedtbd039_posto_atendimento_m] ([co_posto])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_gedtbd042_vinculacao_posto_atendimento_gedtbd039_posto_atendimento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_gedtbd042_vinculacao_posto_atendimento_icotb001_unidades_c] FOREIGN KEY([nu_unidade])
REFERENCES [dbo].[icotb001_unidades_c] ([nu_unidade])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[gedtbd042_posto_atendimento_c] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_gedtbd042_vinculacao_posto_atendimento_icotb001_unidades_c]
GO
```

Comment: 1) Is there anymore details in the error such as field names it is saying are invalid? 2) Do you have any Fluent mapping code? 3) Are you specifying a convention such as in OnModelCreating in the linked MSDN example?  I suspect it is probably using a default convention that appends things to certain fields like an "*Id" suffix that would cause a mismatch with the database.

Comment: 1) The error is: Invalid column name 'tb_franchise_id_franchise'. 2) There is no generated mapping code between then, but there is for the property id_franchise. 3) Yes. But no relations were automaticly created there. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you edit to include the create table statements? the data model is a bit hard to parse through.  I have a feeling your FK do not match the conventions that EF uses.  If so you would need to use attributes to properly map every thing.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your help